# How to convert milliseconds into minutes?

Tags: javascript

i got one more problem if any one have any solution please help me.
Ploblem is like this I want to convert milliseconds into minutes in javascript and then decrement minutes by 60000 milliseconds untill it reaches current time for which i am using this code:-

```
<?php
$date2   = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$currentdate = strtotime($date2);
$targetdate = strtotime('2012-05-09 21:30:00');
?>
<script type=text/javascript>
var currentdate = <?php echo $currentdate; ?>;
var targetdate = <?php echo $targetdate; ?>;
var difference = targetdate - currentdate;

var minutes = Math.floor(difference / 60);
var i = minutes;
var intID;
function decrementMin() {
    if(i==0)
    {
        clearInterval(intID);
        alert('Minute = Congratulation your time begin!');
    }
    if(i>=0){
    document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = i + "minutes";
    i--;
    }
}
decrementMin();
intID = setInterval('decrementMin()', 60000);
</script>
```

The problem is like that their are total 478 seconds and when we convert it into minutes then it become 7.9666 but by using Math.floor() it show's 7 minutes and give alert before .9666 second means before 58 seconds.
If any one have any solution please help me i am waiting for your answer please.

Comment: Why are you doing half of the work in PHP and the other half in JavaScript?

Comment: as i have already use currentdate and targetdate in php so i don't want to convert it again so i have taken it from php code.

Comment: For one thing, you have a `i+"minutes`. If this is your real code - you should take out the quotation marks.

Comment: Another - why `document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = i + "minutes;` and not `innerHTML = i`?

Comment: @JNF i m using document.getElementById('minutes').innerHTML = i + "minutes"; for printing the value of i in a particular div only.

Answer (score 0):

.9666 minutes isn't 9666 seconds - it's 58 seconds