# How to print audio time in format 00:00:00 using AVFundation

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, time, avfoundation

In my app where I use `AVFoundation` I call function `showCurrentAudioProgress()` using `NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "showCurrentAudioProgress", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)` in `viewDidLoad`. I would like to return this kind of time format 00:00:00 but I have a big problem with it. Whole function looks like this:

```
var musicPlayer = AVAudioPLayer()

func showCurrentAudioProgress() {
    self.totalTimeOfAudio = self.musicPlayer.duration
    self.currentTimeOfAudio = self.musicPlayer.currentTime

    let progressToShow = Float(self.currentTimeOfAudio) / Float(self.totalTimeOfAudio)
    self.audioProgress.progress = progressToShow

    var totalTime = self.musicPlayer.duration
    totalTime -= self.currentTimeOfAudio

    self.currentTimeTimer.text = "\(currentTimeOfAudio)"
    self.AudioDurationTime.text = "\(totalTime)"  
}
```

how can I convert time which I recive using `AVAudioPlayer` to 00:00:00?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use NSDateComponentsFormatter .Positional style and zeroFormattingBehavior .Pad to display your time interval as follow:

```
extension NSTimeInterval {
    struct DateComponents {
        static let formatterPositional: NSDateComponentsFormatter = {
            let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
            formatter.allowedUnits = [.Hour,.Minute,.Second]
            formatter.unitsStyle = .Positional
            formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .Pad
            return formatter
        }()
    }
    var positionalTime: String {
        return DateComponents.formatterPositional.stringFromTimeInterval(self) ?? ""
    }
}

print(120.positionalTime)  // 0:02:00
```

If you would like to use string format initialiser you can take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30772571/2303865).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution will be to get `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds` separately and the combine into one string. To improve you can put it into String category or extension.

```
let totalTimeOfAudio = 26343 // number of seconds just for an example

let secondsInMinute = 60
let minuteInHour = 60
let secondsInHour = secondsInMinute * minuteInHour

let hours = Float(totalTimeOfAudio / (secondsInHour))
let minutes = Float(totalTimeOfAudio / minuteInHour % minuteInHour)
let seconds = Float(totalTimeOfAudio % secondsInMinute)

let string: NSString = NSString(format: "%02.f:%02.f:%02.f", hours, minutes, seconds)
```

Comment: something is wrong in `minues` becouse it is still the same value even next minute