# time elapsed in AVPlayer is showing strange numbers in swift

Tags: swift, avplayer

I have the following code to attempt to show the time elapsed of my audio file:

```
    func updateTime() {
    let currentTime = Int(player!.currentTime().value)
    let minutes = currentTime/60
    print(minutes)
    let seconds = currentTime - minutes * 60
    print(seconds)
    time.text = NSString(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes,seconds) as String
}
```

The timer is set in this code in view did load:

```
    play.play()

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(.updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

There are numbers displayed in the lable but they are completely random, so no display of seconds and minutes. What am I doing wrong here? Is it the way I am getting the current Time?

Comment: %d it is for integers. Looks like you are working with Double/NSTimeInterval or Float

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30772571/2303865

Comment: the numbers I am getting are like this:  
15980621,
39,
32657959,
34,
49332843,
18,
65981395,
17,
82654148,
33,
99314348,
47,
115990088,
56,
132647323,
8,
149315021,
16,

Answer (score 0):

I changed this line to:

```
let currentTime = Int(player!.currentTime().value) / Int(player!.currentTime().timescale)
```

I have no idea why this works, but it does the trick!

Comment: "I have no idea why this works, but it works!" the meme about programmer life